# Rest API LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: oracle, azure, api, rest

I have Rest API that has total results = 23000
and it has a limit to get data = 500
so there is any way to put parameter retrieve all data ?

for example is:

```
https://oraclecloud.com/limit=5000
```

but it retrieves only 499 so how I can retrieve all data

thanks

Comment: It seems that there is a throttle for GET requests. 500 per 5 minutes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling

Comment: There is no answer or solution till me :(